# Checking node attribute is empty or null in attribute file

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, devops, chef-solo

How do I check if my attribute contains a a value, an empty string or nil in my attribute file?

Supposed I have this in my default.rb

I am just not sure what is the best way to validate if a node attribute has a value or null?

```
#<> Supply endpoint or not  < clients will supply this value or not in my run list >
default[:my_code][:my_endpoint] = ""

#Option 1
if node[:my_code][:my_endpoint] == ""
    default[:my_code][:my_endpoint] =  'default'
end

#Option 2
if node[:my_code][:my_endpoint].to_s.empty?
    default[:my_code][:my_endpoint] =  'default'
end
```

I currently cannot test this as my environment is down so I just have this question on top of my head for now.  I haven't tried Option 2 actually.. I just got this why googling or if there is a better alternative

Comment: How about `default[:my_code][:my_endpoint] ||=  'default'`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is wrong in this case. You should use [precedence levels](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-precedence) as designed. Set `my_endpoint` to `default` in an attribute file. And override it on any higher level if necessary - recipe/environment/role.